# Using an updated forked pod doesn't have same code locally after pod install

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I forked a pod and made some changes in a branch. In my Podfile, I include

`pod 'Mobile-Buy-SDK', git: 'git@github.com:company-name/mobile-buy-sdk-ios.git', branch: 'zs-mods', submodules: true`

and ran `pod install`.

The main changes in this branch are changing some `internal`s to `public`s in the pod.

Yet when I go to use those properties that should be visible now, I get errors that they're still internal.

I've tried clearing derived data and cleaning but no luck. What should I do here? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cocoapods create local cache for each pod per version. If you didn't change version of this pod (by creating new podspec with new version), local cache is being used.

You can remove this cache by cleaning `${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods`:

`rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"`